# Use of transitive verbs and present continuous

Tags: complementation, infinitive-vs-gerund

I would like to use the transitive verb "implicate". My search on Google lead solely to the result, that it should be followed by a noun (David, downfall, herself, ...). However, can I use this transitive verb with a continuous form of a verb?

To put it simply: I would like to know whether I can use one of these options or both are wrong.

> "This implicates to find a common language." 
>   "This implicates finding a common language."

Comment: What you call "continuous form of a verb" might be better labeled as a _gerund_. In any event, I can't make heads or tails out of your two sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous verb forms are *to be + -ing form of verb*.

A transitive verb is a verb that requires a direct object.

They exist together without issue.

> I kicked the ball.
>
> I am kicking the ball.

However, just because you see an *-ing* word does not mean it's continuous tense, a form of *to be* must precede it.

> This implicates finding a common language.

*Implicates* is not a continuous tense here. The continuous form of this sentence would be *This is implicating finding a common language.*

So you are not really asking about present continuous tense.

What you are doing here is using a verb as an noun, and that noun is falling in the same place as an object.  When you do this, you may need to use the plain verb form, the full infinitive form "to X", or the *-ing* form of the verb.

The rules on which to choose are complex (for example, after *want* you would normally use the full infinitive - e.g. *I want to go to the park.*)  Look at [this](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm) for further help.

In this situation you should use the *-ing* form of the verb as you've done in your second sentence.